# how create many pages with Angular?

Tags: angular, frontend

Hiii,

I have a question regarding my web application.
I'm using Angular for the Front but I don't understand how to create multiple pages.
For example I created differents components for my home page. Which gives me the next tree.

[Angular project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iP2Li.png)

But if I have other pages to do I have no idea where to place them in my project.

Can you help me please

Comment: You can use anugular routing and modules for other pages. Refer : https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: The Angular tour of heroes sample app may be helpful: https://stackblitz.com/angular/ybbdbroqogm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdashboard%2Fdashboard.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there will be a file called `app-routing.module.ts` in the project.
You have to create new `components` i.e. your new pages and give a specific route for them in the app-routing file like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
path: 'home',
component: HomepageComponent
},
{
path: 'about-us',
component: AboutUsComponent
}];
```

and so on.

then in `app.component.ts` you will have to place

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

which will render those pages wherever this `router-outlet` is present when you go to that particular route. For eg. `http://localhost:4200/about-us`